# Moving between view by presentViewController. Whats going wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibaction

Every time that I press the button activating the action above, my screen goes black.
I just want pass to another view (or same) without using the model proposed by storyboard.
What's wrong?

Thanks

```
- (IBAction)goToView:(id)sender {

ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Do you have a `ViewController.xib` file in your project?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't configured your controller's view.

For example try this just before you `presentViewController`...

```
   controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

Your screen will turn orange...

Full example:

```
- (IBAction)goToView:(id)sender {

    ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] 
                                         initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Comment: Thanks.. but i need to do a action to take me to another view. Ex.: Pressing the button > ViewController2

Comment: @user2379431, see my update. It doesn't change your navigation, just configures the view of the controller you are presenting, before you present it.

Comment: So. Do you know how can i move to another viewcontroller? i saw this action, but it did not resolve my problem! Could you help me!?

Comment: @user2379431, when you 'present' a view controller you _are_ moving to it. You can tell this, because if you first set it's view's background color to orange, then you present it, you see your screen turn orange. You have successfully presented that new view controller, who's orange view fills the screen. Consider that code methods and storyboard techniques map to each other: a modal segue does the same job as 'presentViewController`, a push segue is storyboard stand-in for 'pushViewController` in code.

Comment: yeah.. this is it!.. i need a action to move like 'a modal segue', but i need it in a action (line).  Cause i will put a uialert like: "Do you want pass for another view controller?" "OK" (i will use the model) "NO" (i will use the 'nil'). So i need a action that send the user to another view Controller. EX.: a login view controller, the first view where the user may present the login and password, press the button "login", and go to another viewcontroller. understood me? (sorry for my english)